# Extract zip folder in iOS using phone gap 2.9.0

Tags: ios, cordova, zip, unzip

I have used zipUtil plugin to extract the zip folder and Below is the image showing how i used ZipUtil plugin in my application. I am using phone gap 2.9.0 and Xcode 5.1, I am very new in phone gap development and I want to unzip/extract the downloaded zip file from the server.

I am able to download the zip file from server and I am getting path of that file as well, But I am not able to extract that zip file.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <title>Test Page</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="ZipUtil.js"></script>

            <style type="text/css">
                * {
                    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
                }
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

                var localPath;


                function init() {
                    document.addEventListener("deviceready", ready, true);
                }

            function ready() {
                console.log("App is ready.");
            }

            function download() {

                //   var remoteFile = "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6731723/a.zip";
                var remoteFile = "https://github.com/shazron/ZipUtil/archive/master.zip";
                var localFileName = remoteFile.substring(remoteFile.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem) {
                                         fileSystem.root.getFile(localFileName, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
                                                                 localPath = fileEntry.fullPath;
                                                                 console.log("localPath1:" + localPath);
                                                                 if (device.platform === "Android" && localPath.indexOf("file://") === 0) {
                                                                 localPath = localPath.substring(7);
                                                                 }
                                                                 console.log("localPath2 save:" + localPath);
                                                                 var ft = new FileTransfer();
                                                                 ft.download(remoteFile,
                                                                             localPath, function (entry) {
                                                                             console.log("file path:" + entry.fullPath);
                                                                             var linkopen = document.getElementById("openlink");
                                                                             linkopen.style.display = "block";
                                                                             linkopen.href = entry.fullPath;

                                                                             // var dwnldImg = document.getElementById("dwnldImg");
                                                                             //dwnldImg.src = entry.fullPath;
                                                                             //dwnldImg.style.visibility = "visible";
                                                                             //dwnldImg.style.display = "block";
                                                                             }, fail);
                                                                 }, fail);
                                         }, fail);
            }

            function fail(error) {
                console.log("error:" + error.code);
            }

            function unzip(){
                //alert("hi");
                // this is both a zip progress and and result handler
                var win = function(json) {
                    if (json.zipProgress) {
                        // {"zipProgress":{"entryNumber":1,"source":"/path/to/test.zip","filename":"myfolder/myfile.png","entryTotal":10,"zip":false}}
                        console.log((json.zipProgress.zip? "zip" : "unzip") + " entry " + json.zipProgress.entryNumber + "/" + json.zipProgress.entryTotal + " ("+ ((json.zipProgress.entryNumber/json.zipProgress.entryTotal)*100).toFixed(2) + "%)" );

                    } else if (json.zipResult) {
                        // zip ok, and done
                        // {"zipResult":{"zip":false,"source":"/path/to/test.zip","target":"/path/to/targetfolder/"}}

                        console.log((json.zipResult.zip? "zip" : "unzip") + " OK: " + JSON.stringify(json));
                    }
                }

                // handles failure
                var fail = function(obj) {
                    if (obj && obj.zipResult) {
                        // zip failed, and done
                        // {"zipResult":{"zip":false,"source":"/path/to/test.zip","target":"/path/to/targetfolder/"}}
                        console.log((obj.zipResult.zip? "zip" : "unzip") + " FAIL: " + JSON.stringify(obj));
                    } else {
                        // general failure message
                        console.log("FAIL: " + obj);
                    }
                }

                var zu = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/ziputil");
                zu.unzip(win, fail, localPath, localPath+'/unzip/');

            }
            </script>
            </head>

    <body onload="init();">
        <a href="#" onclick="download();">Download file</a>

        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="#" id="openlink" style="display:none;font-size:larger;" onclick="unzip(); return false;">open</a>

    </body>

</html>
```

In the above code I used ZipUtil plugin but its showing error,

```
2013-12-05 15:10:38.739 TestUnzip[6934:a0b] CDVPlugin class ZipUtil (pluginName: ZipUtil) does not exist.
2013-12-05 15:10:38.740 TestUnzip[6934:a0b] ERROR: Plugin 'ZipUtil' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
```

Comment: Have you added the plugin to the config.xml?

Comment: Yes, I have added plugin in the config.xml as well.